# Move Languages Module from Footer to Header

Tags: magento-1.7, module

I want to move the Language Change options from the footer to header. To do this I simply moved this code in the page.xml file of my current template:

```
<block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
```

Previously it was written under

```
<block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
```

Now I have moved it under:

```
<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
```

Now when I refreshed the page, it is removed from footer, but doesn't show up in header. Can anyone tell what else is needed to be changed for this to take effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add the following code in the file `page/html/header.phtml`

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language');?>
```

Put this in the HTML where you want the switch to be displayed.